# Convert entry log (csv) to list of names based on whether they entered on each day

Tags: python, csv, report

I have a raw printout from a Security System that records and logs actions taken by the system.

The facility manager wants to have a report with a list of names based on if they entered on that day.

i.e.
17/1/2019
John Smith
Beth Hook
16/1/2019
etc.

The CSV file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ABj1gxFG-1j41jai6_TjXsezHXvd2qQL
*Names have been changed to protect the identity of clients

It provides User's names already so I would think the steps would be:

1. Get Date
2. Check Name
3. If null, ignore
4. Else, Check Array of names
5. If none exist, Add to array
6. Else, ignore
7. Repeat

It's possible to export a CSV for each day so the program doesn't necessarily have to interpret multiple dates at once.

I don't know how to use python which appears to be most solutions so any help is greatly appreciated. Although I don't really mind what language it is in or if I need to install other programs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) a command line utility, with

```
mlr --csv filter '$User=~".+"' then cut -o -f Date,User \
then uniq -a "Example Report.csv" | \
mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output  nest --implode --values --across-records -f User | \
sed -r 's/(,|;)/\n/g'
```

you have

```
17/1/19
Beth Hook
CEO
John Smith
16/1/19
Peter Man
Jess Hare
Finn Tomb
John Smith
Finance
15/1/19
CEO
Peter Man
member 34
Beth Hook
John Smith
14/1/19
SYSTEM USER
Bin Stick
Peter Man
CEO
Partner
L Stick
Tie Cooler
member 16
John Smith
13/1/19
Partner
Peter Man
11/1/19
Wheels Hireman
Bunny
10/1/19
Bunny
member 36
Mary Stone
9/1/19
Bunny
Jus Wall
member 36
```